# Generic Repository Filter Child Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am using a generic repository to query my database [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). All my entities inherit a base class which has a property `Active`, I set `Active` to `false` when the user deletes it. The problem I am facing now is that while the code below works fine for main entity I could not figure out how to return only `Active` child activities.

I have tried using dynamic linq but not successfully. Is there any way to do this except the most obvious using linq on child entities?

```
 public virtual TEntity GetById(object id,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        if (includeProperties.Length > 0)
        {
            query = includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }
        else
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

        if (query.Any())
        {
            return query.First();
        }
        return query.First();
    }
```

Comment: You could try to use reflection to get the children of your entity and then apply additional filters using dynamic LINQ. Never used dynamic LINQ, so cant give full answer, but this seems like the direction to go if you really want to avoid the caller to filter

Comment: Stop creating generic repositories!

Answer (score 2):

You should create filter for that ([EntityFramework.Filters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Filters/)):

```
public interface IActive
{
    public bool Active {get;set;}
}

public class MyClass : IActive
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public bool Active {get;set;}
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{   
    modelBuilder.Conventions
       .Add(FilterConvention.Create<IActive, bool>("MyFilter", (entity, Active) => entity.Active);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var filter = context.EnableFilter("MyFilter");
filter.SetParameter("Active", true);

var item = GetById(1);
//now inside GetById method 'item' and all it's children will be filtered with "Active == true" condition

context.DisableFilter("MyFilter");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of options :

```
public virtual TEntity GetById(object id,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = GetActive();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        if (includeProperties.Length > 0)
        {
            query = includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
        }
        else
        {
            return DbSet.Find(id);
        }

        if (query.Any())
        {
            return query.First();
        }
        return query.First();
    }

public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetActive()
{
    return 
        DbSet.Where(a => a.Active);
}
```

Comment: We are already able to filter the parent entities but not the child entities.